# New ads on MSE.

Tags: discussion, support, status-norepro

As of a minute ago I'm getting ads on every MSE page I visit.

I get a vertical one on the left and an horizontal on the bottom.

I'm hoping this is some sort of virus my computer got, which seems possible since no one asked about this yet.

Can you please confirm this?

I really can't be arsed with these ads every time.

**Edit:** after I opened about fifteen new MSE pages, the bottom ad seems to have disappearead and I'm now only bothered by the vertical one.

I also scrolled my mouse over the ad and it links to MSE, so unfortunately it seems like it is a MSE feature. It seems to be related to this: `http://www.topictorch.com/appsupport.aspx?p=RGlWYXB0b24=&d=ZGl2YXB0b24uYml6`. Can in it be turned off permanently? I know I can close the ad each time it appears.

Screenshot of vertical ad:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This behavior (including the term "Related searches") is inconsistent with SE, in particular MSE, and rather consistent with sites whose domain expired and were taken by resellers.

Comment: @JonEricson Great, thanks. I gotta go now, I'll take care of it later. I posted a link to it in my question, but since the layout looks so much like the SE blog (or maybe it's something else SE related), I didn't pay much attention to it.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: It's up to you all.  It probably depends on how likely the question (and my now answer) will be to help future members of Math.SE.

Comment: Since the page you linked to seems to be some kind of spam, I've edit your post so that it does not link directly to that page. (So that we do not increase the PageRank of that site by linking to it directly from SE network.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Three words: Ad Block Plus. Thank me later...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those ads are not from Stack Exchange, but are likely some sort of invasive program on your machine.  [Google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=Topic+Torch) this is a virus and offers some means to remove it.

Good luck and I'm sorry you got infected. :(

Comment: Took care of it. Thanks.

Comment: The very same thing happened to me, albeit on Wikipedia, some Inkfruit ads popped up on the vertical margin each time. Really irritating. Fixed that by doing something with my browser, don't exactly remember.