# How to keep ads from appearing on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, advertising

I find the ads about non-mathematical things annoying. I tried to click on one to report it but nothing worked. Is there a way a user of Stack Exchange can get rid of such ads? Some seem to appear for a few days and then go away, others then appear a few days later. Thanks for any information.

Added: One such was "Enterprise Flash Storage Solutions" which had an IBM logo on it. It seemed to be about some technology involving use of "clouds" which to me is not math at all.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of said ads? From [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33296/are-there-ads-on-mathematics-stack-exchange?r=SearchResults&s=2|34.0897), its not clear if there are any ads on math.SE, and you are afterall asking in the math.se specific meta (It also does not sound like you're talking about community ads, which are at least somewhat related to maths, but would be good to confirm)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for the response. I don't know how to get a screen shot of the ad. I added something to my question about a specific ad and why I think it's not about math.

Comment: I would be rather pleased if you could try to screenshot one the next time you see it (or even take a photo:) ) with enough context in the image to know that it is on Math.SE; you could then provide an answer to the above linked post. Also, its possible for some computer viruses or browser "add-ons" or other such things to inject ads into websites you browse. One example [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11245/new-ads-on-mse). I still have not personally seen any ads on math.se

Comment: Thanks again @CalvinKhor for following up. I'm not too computer savy--- could you give a link to some info about how to take a screeen shot?

Comment: I see you managed! Thank you very much for the picture and sorry I couldnt make good instructions in time. There's a "report this ad" button underneath the ad, does it not work?

Comment: I think I got it to work, not very well I admit. I inserted some kind of screenshot into the question at the end.

Comment: @CalvinKhor The report this ad" button takes one to a screen, which in turn asks for a screen shot. So before,m I couldn't go further. Now it might work... still I find these ads quite annoying. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126339/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-calvin-khor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution (which is not specific to this site, but works more or less everywhere) is to use a version of an 'ad blocker' add-on for your browser. For example, [here](https://getadblock.com/), though I am in no way endorsing this particular choice.

Answer (score 4):

As Pedro has already mentioned, the best solution is to install an adblocker. [Here](https://www.tomsguide.com/uk/round-up/best-adblockers-privacy-extensions) is an article about "the best ad blockers in 2021". For what it's worth, I use [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) on Google Chrome, and it works perfectly.